# Applying a bit mask using lc3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm currently taking a course on assembly, and have ran into an issue that even after researching online and talking to the prof teaching it, i'm still at a complete loss as to how to implement it.

In a nutshell, I'm looking to know how to implement a bitmask on a value. For example, if say you wanted to take a 16 bit value (1000 0011 1100 0001), and convert it to this (0000 0000 0111 1111), you'd apply a mask of this value (0000 0000 0111 1111) using what I was told is an OR command....except I see no such command in lc3's documentation that was provided with the course. Perhaps it's done in a different way, but I've as of yet found no documentation outlining it in my travels.

In summary, have no idea how to apply a bitmask to a value using lc3 assembly, have no luck with resources available to me, anyone here that understands the material better then I have any helpful advice on how this would be done?

EDIT: Yes this is homework, but as you can see, I've exhausted my other options.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about lc3 and only minor knowledge about assembly. 
But if you want to apply a bitmask, you want to load up your values to a register each.
And then either do a AND or OR instruction on those registers.

Comment: No, you could never get that result from the original with any logical operator. Your material/teacher has been giving out wrong information, or you've misunderstood.

Comment: @MrSykkox I think that's where I'm getting thrown is how to apply an OR instruction. An AND seems straight forward (aka do an AND R1, R0, R1 or something like that). My search online for such instruction data has been fruitless and then some.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'd wager more on me misunderstanding, as everything else seems to have clicked.

Comment: As Sami has pointed out, that's not an `OR` operation, at least not a single one by itself. Anyway, if you need an `OR` you can implement it with `NOT` and `AND` using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this, this is how I solved this, and how you can do an OR instruction in lc3 assembly

```
;Initialize the variables
.ORIG   x3000
LD  R0, valueRO     
LD  R1, valueR1     
LD  R2, lowOrderZero

;The OR instruction begins now
NOT R3, R0 ;Inverse the value in Register 0 to Register 3
NOT R4, R2 ;Inverse the value in Register 2 to Register 4
AND R5, R3, R4 ;Select either the largest or the closest value and store in R5 (not certain on this one)
NOT R0, R5 ;Inverse the value in Register 5 to Register 0

HALT

valueRO     .FILL   x0014
valueR1     .FILL   x0023
lowOrderZero    .FILL   x007F
```

With this example, I tool the value in R0, and applied a bit mask of 0000 0000 0111 1111 to the value in R0

[Special thanks to the Comp Sci instructors at the University of Auckland](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci210s1c/tutorials/04/CS210_4.pdf)